# how to set date default value in react edit form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, render, edit

I am setting date value as follows:

```
                <div className="form-group row">
                    <label className="control-label col-md-12" htmlFor="fldDob" >Date of Birth</label>
                    <div className="col-md-4">
                        <input className="form-control" type="date" name="fldDob" value={this.state.empData.fldDob} onChange={e => this.state.empData.FldDob = new Date(e.target.value)} required />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

But the date is not being displayed in edit form. What am I doing wrong with the date?

When I check in console, I am getting following value in this.state.empData.FldDob: "2020-05-27T00:00:00"

I have tried value={this.state.empData.FldDob.toISOString().substring(0, 10)} but it is giving error "TypeError: this.state.empData.fldDob.toISOString is not a function"

Comment: `this.state.empData.FldDob` is a string and You can directly use `substring()` like `this.state.empData.FldDob.substring(0, 10)`. `toISOString()` is available on `Date` object.

Comment: there is major mistake in your onChange function you can't directly mutate state using this.state.empData.FldDob = new Date(e.target.value) as state is immutable there is method for setting state this.setState to manipulate state you can do this way
`e => this.setState({ empData: { ...this.state.empData, FldDob: new Date(e.target.value)  }  }) `

Comment: @AmeerHamza onChange function is working fine. Date is being set in state and is saved in database. Only problem is displaying the date when opening the form for edit.

Comment: @HassanImam this.state.empData.fldDob is a Date and this.state.empData.FldDob.substring(0, 10) is giving an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined"